SFMC In-App messae silent push issue iOS
Currently SFMC in using the silent push mechanism to download the in-app message content in iOS. And its applicable for Opted-In users while for opted out users, this process happens only when app is in foreground.
Is there any way we can block/deny to send the silent push to opted-in user for in-app message delivery ? We don't want to use the silent push mechanism. We want do download every in-app message when app is in foregrounded state. The same mechanism which is implemented for opted-out users.
When SFMC send the silent push, it awake your application in background and some app gets launch unnecessarily. It results in some unnecessary API calls as well. We want to avoid this silent push feature for in-app messages. Please suggest if there is any approach or any setting which we can changes from SFMC dashboard or any change in SDK configuration ?
